# Programmatic Access Control on PHP based website hosted on IIS using Active Directory?

Tags: php, active-directory, iis-8

**Background:**

I have a PHP based website on IIS8 with Active Directory integration, where I need to provide different levels of access control. For instance:

```
Customer Service
- View Transactions
- View Customers
Finance
- Edit Transactions
- View Transactions
- View Customers
```

Currently, we are using IIS's AD integration to control login to the secure parts of the site, but cannot segregate out rights (eg: example above) based on groups.

**Question:**

Is there a way (via PHP) of using AD for more than just simple login, where I can determine what AD group a person is in so I can programmatically base my page creation on their group?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out to satisfy my needs for one single login mechanism, no separate lookup accounts, different group rights, etc, this is really simple and doesn't require LDAP at all.

- Turn off "anonymous authenticaion" for the site in IIS.
- Turn on Windows Authentication for the site in IIS.
- Create website subfolders that represent each group.
- Put one file (empty or a byte) in each folder.
- Remove ALL Windows AD access rights (except for your programmers/Admins). That includes IUSR - remove it too - to the sub folder.
- Add access rights to the folder(s) by group(s).
- Write a tiny bit of PHP that checks the    existence of "[GroupNameFolder]/PermFile.txt" (or whatever you name it).

That's literally it. No LDAP libraries, no LDAP calls. IIS will take care of it all.

If the file exists, they are in the AD group the folder represents. If it doesn't, then they are not in the group. Then, programmatically, if I got an "exists" on "Finance" (eg: my question's example), I allow them "Edit Transactions" access.

**DISADVANTAGE:**

This is NOT cross platform safe (though the methods can be adapted pretty easily to other platforms).

Answer (score 0):

It depends. Your site uses NTLM or checking AD credentials by direct request to your AD server? 
In first case(NTLM) web site receives only a few data about account (samaccountname, domain), so it knows nothing about custom fields in AD which can contain data about permissions, and you need to control access rights in your website, maybe you can write some sync tool that will export access from AD and put it to your site's database. 
In second case, your site have user's access to AD, and probably (depends on your AD settings) can read some access-specific fields in AD.
My answer based on my experience of writing AD auth on php site working under nginx/linux, situation may be different in IIS-based php environment.

Comment: Alas, this is possible, group based. We also run IBM FileNet, where the web front end is on a Solaris box running under a WebLogic instance. It integrates directly with Active Directory and all access rights are directly controlled via assigning people to Active Directory Groups. 

So, I know it's possible - but IBM obviously isn't going to tell us how, nor do I think it would be easy to port over a Java on Solaris in WebLogic solution to PHP on Windows in IIS. ;-)

Comment: If you always know user's account - there is a way, you can use php_ldap extension https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.ldap.php and check user's permission on the php-side of your site. I mean, use AD RO user account for  requests from backend, and literally find user's DN and read it permissions, when you need it.

Comment: Worst case, I will suggest that method, but currently, the business decision was made to secure IIS using AD - that works fine, and can be done via a group. They would prefer to not have to add another log-on mechanism. The Windows stations are passing it through to IIS to AD right now. But, thanks, worse case, I will push to move it to "PHP Land" and require login. PERSONALLY, I prefer them having to actually log in so I can also actually time out the connection in case they walk away before their computer self locks, so, *I* like your suggestion.

Comment: May be I haven't understand you correctly, but this doesnt require additional log-in.
User  Alex, whith samaccount record "alexatitsecurity" goes to protected part of web site. As I understand you, site knows that this is alexatitsecurity. And it can start request to AD, using tech account, to check is "alexatitsecurity" memberOf "siteAdmin" group.

Comment: Site doesn't know password. The code end doesn't know anything. IIS either allows access or not, all at the server level, based on Windows logon to the box (or by using web logon mechanisms to authenticate).